# NSDates not sorting properly

Tags: sorting, nsdate, nssortdescriptor

I have stored NSDates using core data. I now want to display these dates in a table view. When I display these NSDates I am using this sort descriptor, see below. The problem is, is that it is not sorting it properly. I want it to sort sequentially. 1:00 am, 2:00 am,...6:00 pm, 7:00 pm, etc. When  it displays the nsdates, its seems to be just sorting it some way which i don't know, kind of random like. Any help in how to display these NSDates in the right order, would be great! Thanks so much

```
///timePicker is the NSDate entity of my stored NSDates
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"timePicker" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)]];
```

Input

```
 NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
 entry.timePicker = currentDate;
```

OutPut

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
NSDate *currentTime = entry.timePicker;
self.timeLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime];
```

Comment: Please include sample input and output.

Comment: I'm don't understand how that code relates to the sorting problem you're talking about. Can you post a sample list of dates, the way you expect them to be sorted, and the way they actually are sorted?

Comment: @JoshCaswell ok josh, here is what i have noticed after further looking into the problem. I have a uipicker that can set the date. If the user selects the date via the picker, the dates are in the correct order. However, if the user does NOT use the picker and just uses the auto populated current time, then the current time is put at the top of the list, NOT IN ORDER. Both the picker times and the auto populated current time([NSDate date]) are stored in the timePicker entity. Does that make sense? What other information do you need from me to help?

Comment: I figured it out. I was not converting the NSDate into the correct format. It is all solved now. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is merely one of display. The *dates* are sorting correctly *by date-time*, so for example January 1, 2010 at 10.30 AM is sorting before January 2, 2010 at 9.30 AM. But then you are *displaying* only the hour and minute, so what you *see* is that the string "10:30 AM" precedes the string "9:30 AM".

Comment: A Holmesian deduction.